# While listing the json data in angular 7 getting an error "Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed"

Tags: angular7

While listing the json data in angular 7 getting an error "Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed"

This is my component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers:[ApiService]
})
 export class AppComponent {
 Form:any[]=[]

  constructor(private api:ApiService){}

ngOnInit(){
  this.getForms();

}

getForms=()=>{
 this.api.getAllForms().subscribe(
   data=>{
    this.Form=data;
    console.log(data);
  },
  error=>{
    console.log(error);
  }
  );
}
}
```

This is my component.html where I just want to list the fullname.

```
 <ul>
  <li *ngFor="let form of Form">
  <h2>{{form.fullname}}</h2>
  </li>
  </ul>
```

This is my service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

baseurl= "http://127.0.0.1:8000";
httpHeaders=new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'});

constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getAllForms(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.baseurl+'/forms/',
    {headers: this.httpHeaders});
  }
}
```

[This is what I get in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtWAW.png)

Comment: `this.Form=data; console.log(data);` whats your data returning here. Add the response for better understanding and that helps us to solve your issue as well.

Comment: I have just edited the problem with the error that I get in console

Answer (score 0):

you must pass as array as `getAllForms(): Observable<any[]>`  instead of `getAllForms(): Observable<any>` and at every other place

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

baseurl= "http://127.0.0.1:8000";
httpHeaders=new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'});

constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getAllForms(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.baseurl+'/forms/',
    {headers: this.httpHeaders});
  }
}
```

Comment: getAllForms(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.baseurl+'/forms/',
    {headers: this.httpHeaders});
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

@Sudeep Sharma, I didn't found any variable with the name `fullname` in your console data and change your `getAllForms()` return type to `Observable<any[]>` that will return the list of forms.

> **Service.ts**

```
  getAllForms(): Observable<any[]> {
       return this.http.get(this.baseurl+'/forms/',{headers: this.httpHeaders});
  }
```